# Convert from slidy to powerpoint with pandoc or something else?

Tags: powerpoint, pandoc, slidy

I'd like to convert a *slidy* presentation to powerpoint. I tried using pandoc:

```
pandoc -f html+tex_math_dollars+tex_math_single_backslash test.html  -o test.pptx
```

Does create a powerpoint file, but the file doesn't have separate slides, all the text is one slide, probably because the above command doesn't tell pandoc to recognize that the html is **slidy**.

I found commands for pandoc to convert TO slidy but nothing about converting FROM slidy.

Comment: Slidy is supported *only* as an output format, as evident from running `pandoc --list-input-formats` and `pandoc --list-output-formats`. It should be possible to write a [pandoc filter](https://pandoc.org/filters.html) to add `HorizontalRule` elements between divs with class `slide`. This should break the document up as desired. Can you post a small example document?

Comment: Ah, thanks! I'm not that familiar with using pandoc directly. I was able to hack a solution by first converting to latex, then converting the latex to powerpoint. But I'm not sure how fragile that approach is and I'd bet there's an audience for a more general solution. I'll try to post a minimal html code asap, but for readers, can get an example by selecting the default slidy document in RStudio and knit.